# woocommerce - wrong widget bar on single product page

Tags: wordpress, widget, woocommerce

ive a problem that the widget area is not showing correct
in the Single Product page of wocommerce, wordpress.

Here the live link 
http://www.bonindesign.de/kunden/tomute/produkt/testo-4ro/

If you scroll below, you see that the widget area is hanging in the footer.

Can you help me with that ?

Thanks alot
Alpha

Answer (score 0):

It's something to do with the closing div on line 273.

Comment: can you specify this ?